# Setting up reverse proxy Nginx + Gunicorn/Django REST - 404 Not Found

Tags: django, nginx, django-rest-framework, gunicorn

I have a setup with Nginx as web server and Gunicorn as application server serving a Django REST API.

Nginx is listening at port 80 and gunicorn at port 8000 (I launch gunicorn using this command):

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 cdm_api.wsgi -t 200 --workers=3
```

and when I launch the petition to port 8000, I am able to access to the API running for instance:

```
curl -d "username=<user>&password=<pass>" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/concept
```

However, when I try to make the petition though Nginx acting as reverse proxy, I get 404 Not Found Error:

```
curl -d "username=<user>&password=<pass>" -X POST http://127.0.0.1:80/api/concept
```

Here is my nginx conf file:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen  [::]:80;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;

    location  /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }

    location / {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Let me know if more information is needed. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is now solved, the config file was misplaced.

Answer (score 0):

So

gunicorn will create a sock file and you will have to map your proxy_pass with the sock file created, for now you are mapping to your localhost:8000 for this you will have to run the django runserver command so that nginx can find a server running on port 8000.

something like -

```
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        #proxy_pass http://unix:/home/abc/backend/social.sock;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/abc/backend/backend.sock;
    }
```

gunicorn make it possible to serve django at production, you don't have to command runserver everytime. Make sure gunicorn restarts everytime when server reboots.

Comment: gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 cdm_api.wsgi -t 200 --workers=3; this for for testime that gunicorn is doing its work.

Comment: Thanks, but I realised I was asking to wrong port. I edited my question. Regarding your answer, is there any way to configure this without setting gunicorn as sock file?